# WCF add new setting for each call

Tags: asp.net-mvc, wcf, iis, web-config, runtime

I am facing a problem and I don't know if my solution is do-able. I have an ASP.NET MVC app which do request to a WCF service (both are hosted in IIS).

In the web app, I identify each user by Windows authentification and get their groups, roles, etc. from active directory.

BUT according to user groups, I need to change some settings in my WCF service. In my idea I'm looking a way to change the settings of WCF service (it need to be in the web.config, mandatory) and I'm really not sure if it's possible, because I think each call to the WCF should create a new instance of web.config, but for now it's just a simple file.

What do you think ?

Thanks !

Comment: Web.config is not the right place to do it. It contains configuration of application, not users, and if you save/modify Web.config, application will restart.
What kind of different behavior does the service need to be?

Comment: Hi Ricardo, to be simple, the service call another windows form application, and to do this call I need to put in the web.config of my service some settings. But these settings are different according to the group of user.

Comment: I guess, you want to change service behavior rather settings. Would be nice to know what exactly do you want to achieve. Which settings/behavior should be different?

Comment: Is the Windows Form application hosting another service?  As @RicardoPontual indicated, changing the web.config will restart the service.  My recommendation is that you have your service programatically configure the call to the WinForm application, that way it can do it based on the credentials supplied by the user that called the service.

Comment: So, ASP MVC app pass by a WCF library to call the DLL of a Windos form app, and at the end, the Windows form app, call a database, but I need to use the workflow of the Windows form app. The DLL need a connection string and this connection string is in the web.config of WCF library. I need to change dynamically this connection string for each call to the WCF.